# Use virtual machine to simultaneously boot into windows?

Tags: virtualization

I am currently dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 on my work computer. Don't like having to shut down and reboot into Windows two or three times a day, but some of the software I need only runs in Windows. I want to take my existing Windows installation and just run it in a VM on Ubuntu. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, as I remember reading that doing what you (and me too!) want to do could mess up the Windows install, but [this how to](http://fds-team.de/cms/articles/2013-12/use-a-real-windows-7-partition-in-virtualbox-kvm-vmware-player-u.html) seems quite extensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this successfully many times and do as you would like to do daily. I actually have several VMs depending on my needs (XP, Win 7, Win 2008, various Linux). One can P2V (physical to virtual) using VMWare's converter package (http://www.vmware.com/products/converter), then you can either use the free VMWare Player or VirtualBox (I mostly use VirtualBox). You can attach the machine you've created in VMWare converter to VirtualBox.

It helps to have a little extra RAM to do this kind of thing, and also I've found that an SSD makes a huge difference. I end up suspending my VMs (not shutting them down) and the jump to life in a few seconds.

P.S. depending on your apps, Wine or the variants like PlayOnLinux (or CrossOver Linux) can be very usable so no VM is necessary. I have several apps that I run this way (Office 2010, FoxIT PDF Reader, Photoshop CS2, etc...)

Comment: The software I needed was some grading software used by my work that they made themselves, I couldn't get it to run at all through wine. This worked great, though!